# Adapting a GNUPLOT cable modeling script for MATLAB - lsqcurvefit issue

Tags: matlab, gnuplot

I found a GNUPLOT script for cable modeling that I am trying to use. [Here's a link to the original script](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/tech-articles/an-improved-and-simple-cable-simulation-model.pdf)

I've ran into problems using this script on my Windows computer though, and I believe the issue is due to the use of Linux exclusive terminals within the script. Specifically "terminal table" and "terminal x11". So I've been trying to adapt the script for MATLAB, here's what I have so far:

```
% Frequencies of interest
fmin = 1e+6; % minimum frequency (Hz)
fmax = 1e9; % maximum frequency (Hz)
fscale=1e9;
% Physical constants
u = 1.26e-6; % magnetic permeability (H/m)
c = 300e+6; % speed of light (m/s)

% Line-specific constants for cable
sigma = 58e+6; % copper conductivity (S/m)
z0 = 50; % characteristic impedance (Ohms)
er = 2.3; % relative dielectric constant RG58U cable (solid Polyethylene)
tand = 0.00035; % loss tangent/dissipation factor (polyethylene)
w = 2 * pi * 4.5 * 10^-4; % cross-sectional cable width (m)
% l is line length (m)
l = 30;

% Attenuation constants
a1 = (l / (2 * w * z0)) * sqrt(pi * u / sigma); % skin effect. Same as Equation 6.
a2 = (l * pi * tand * sqrt(er)) / c; % Dielectric Effect. Same as Equation 7.
disp(['a1=', num2str(a1)]);
disp(['a2=', num2str(a2)]);

% Calculate the loss including skin and dielectric effects
f = logspace(log10(fmin), log10(fmax), 1000); % Frequency points
response = exp(-a1 * sqrt(f) - a2 * f); % Frequency response calculation

% Store the frequency response in a file called droop.csv
data = [f', response']; % Combine frequency and response into a matrix
data = data'; % Transpose the data matrix
dlmwrite('droop.csv', data, 'delimiter', ',', 'precision', 10); % Save data to CSV file

% Define pole/zero and pole equations
% pole/zero
pz = @(x, p, z) (1 + ((2 * pi * x) / (2 * pi * z)).^2) ./ (1 + ((2 * pi * x) / (2 * pi * p)).^2);
% pole
p = @(x, p) 1 ./ (1 + ((2 * pi * x) / (2 * pi * p)).^2); % Eq2

% Define initial estimates for poles and zeroes
wp1 = 7e-3*fscale; wz1 = 8e-3*fscale;
wp2 = 6e-2*fscale; wz2 = 7e-2*fscale;
wp3 = 2.5e-1*fscale; wz3 = 3.5e-1*fscale;
wp4 = 0.25*fscale; wz4 = 0.1*fscale;
wp5 = 0.5*fscale; wz5 = 1*fscale;
wp6 = 12*fscale;

poles0 = [wp1, wz1, wp2, wz2, wp3, wz3, wp4, wz4, wp5, wz5, wp6]; % Initial estimates for poles


% Fit the data to find the poles using lsqcurvefit
poles = lsqcurvefit(@(x, poles) sqrt(pz(x, poles(1), poles(2)) .* pz(x, poles(3), poles(4)) .* pz(x, poles(5), poles(6)) .* pz(x, poles(7), poles(8)) .* pz(x, poles(9), poles(10)) .* p(x, poles(11))), poles0, data(1, :), data(2, :));


% Define the cable response function
f6 = @(x, poles) sqrt(pz(x, poles(1), poles(2)) .* pz(x, poles(3), poles(4)) .* pz(x, poles(5), poles(6)) .* pz(x, poles(7), poles(8)) .* pz(x, poles(9), poles(10)) .* p(x, poles(11)));

% Overlay the Cable Characteristics vs the Mathematical Fit
figure;
semilogx(data(1, :), log(data(2, :)), 'b'); % Plot physical response
hold on;
semilogx(data(1, :), log(f6(data(1, :), poles)), 'r'); % Plot mathematical fit
title('Cable Response via Physical Description vs Mathematical Fit');
xlabel('Frequency');
ylabel('log(Amplitude)');
legend('Physical Response', 'Mathematical Fit');
grid on;

% Calculate Rs and Cs for pole/zero schematic normalized for a 50 ohm characteristic impedance
% Pole Zero1
r1 = 50 * ((poles(2) / poles(1)) - 1);
c1 = 1 / (2 * pi * 50 * poles(2));
% Pole Zero2
r2 = 50 * ((poles(4) / poles(3)) - 1);
c2 = 1 / (2 * pi * 50 * poles(4));
% Pole Zero3
r3 = 50 * ((poles(6) / poles(5)) - 1);
c3 = 1 / (2 * pi * 50 * poles(6));
% Pole Zero4
r4 = 50 * ((poles(8) / poles(7)) - 1);
c4 = 1 / (2 * pi * 50 * poles(8));
% Pole Zero5
r5 = 50 * ((poles(10) / poles(9)) - 1);
c5 = 1 / (2 * pi * 50 * poles(10));
% Last Pole
c6 = 1 / (2 * pi * 50 * poles(11));
disp(['r1=', num2str(r1)]);
disp(['c1=', num2str(c1)]);
disp(['r2=', num2str(r2)]);
disp(['c2=', num2str(c2)]);
disp(['r3=', num2str(r3)]);
disp(['c3=', num2str(c3)]);
disp(['r4=', num2str(r4)]);
disp(['c4=', num2str(c4)]);
disp(['r5=', num2str(r5)]);
disp(['c5=', num2str(c5)]);
disp(['c6=', num2str(c6)]);

% Pause to keep the figure open until the user presses a key
pause;
```

I'm very unfamiliar with coding in GNUPLOT and have not used anonymous functions before in MATLAB and I'm running into an error when I try to run this script. When I try to use lsqcurvefit in this line:

```
poles = lsqcurvefit(@(x, poles) sqrt(pz(x, poles(1), poles(2)) .* pz(x, poles(3), poles(4)) .* pz(x, poles(5), poles(6)) .* pz(x, poles(7), poles(8)) .* pz(x, poles(9), poles(10)) .* p(x, poles(11))), poles0, data(1, :), data(2, :));
```

I get the following error: Error using lsqcurvefit (line 286)
Function value and YDATA sizes are not equal.

I checked the size of data(1,:), data(2,:) to verify that they were the same size (1x1000). I believe those are the "function value" and "YDATA" input arguments that the error message says have different sizes, however they are the same size.

I also checked the size of the anonymous function using a test input:

```
% Define the anonymous function
anonymousFunc = @(x, poles) sqrt(pz(x, poles(1), poles(2)) .* pz(x, poles(3), poles(4)) .* pz(x, poles(5), poles(6)) .* pz(x, poles(7), poles(8)) .* pz(x, poles(9), poles(10)) .* p(x, poles(11)));

% Define the test input
testInput = data(1, :); % Use the frequency data as the test input

% Evaluate the anonymous function
functionValues = anonymousFunc(testInput, poles0);

disp(size(functionValues)); % Check the size of the function values
```

This also showed a size of 1x1000. The only other input to the lsqcurvefit is my poles0 matrix containing the initial estimates for the poles and zeros. poles0 is 1x11, but I don't think that I can change that to be 1x1000. Any help with getting this script working in MATLAB would be very appreciated. This is actually my first time posting a question on this site so if there's any information or context that I'm not providing but people normally give, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You asked for MATLAB, however, I quickly looked at the original gnuplot script. The documentation is from 2012. In all gnuplot versions I checked (starting from 4.2.6, Sept. 2009) there is no terminal `table`, but you can use the plotting style `with table` and plot to a file. Maybe it was a special option during compilation from source? So, I don't know which gnuplot version or option they used.

Anyway, I tried to get the gnuplot script to run. My default terminal is `wxt`.
The following (slightly adapted) script gives the result below.

**Script:**

```
# GNUPLOT File that:
#1) Calculates the frequency response after calculating the skin effect and dielectric effects, using only the physical parameters of the cable.
#2) It then plots the frequency response caused by these physical parameters and stores that information in a file called droop.csv.
#3) We then define a pole/zero and pole response, based on frequency, the pole, and the zero.
#4) We cascade five pole/zeroes and one pole.
#5) We then calculate the six poles (wp1 to wp6) and the five zeroes (wz1 to wz2) using the GNUPLOT "Fit" function.
#6) We then calculate a SPICE-equivalent schematic with Rs and Cs defined by the poles and zeroes.
#7) We plot the calculated physical response and overlay that with the mathematically calculated fit, based on a 6 pole/5 pole fit.
#8) The Rs and Cs are passed onto a SPICE high-level schematic, and this models the cable. This schematic can then run AC or transient simulations.
#9) Lastly, we run the SPICE model and obtain the response and compare this to the physical response and the mathematical response. All three responses must lie on top of one another to ensure a good model fit.

# Frequencies of interest
fmin = 1e+6    # minimum frequency (Hz)
fmax = 1e9     # maximum frequency (Hz)

# Physical constants
u=1.26e-6      # magnetic permeability (H/m)
c=300e+6       # speed of light (m/s)

# Line-specific constants for cable
sigma=58e+6         # copper conductivity (S/m)
z0=50           # characteristic impedance (Ohms)
er=2.3          # relative dielectric constant RG58U cable (solid Polyethylene)
tand=0.00035    # loss tangent/dissipation factor (polyethylene)
w=2*pi*4.5*10-4 # cross-sectional cable width (m)

#l is line length (m)
l=30

# Attenuation constants
a1=(l/(2*w*z0))*sqrt(pi*u/sigma)  # skin effect. Same as Equation 6.
a2=(l*pi*tand*sqrt(er))/c         # Dielectric Effect. Same as Equation 7.
print "a1=", a1
print "a2=", a2

# Plot the loss including skin and dielectric effects
plot [f=fmin:fmax] exp(-a1*sqrt(f)-a2*f)        # Plotting Equation 8.

# set terminal table   # ??? don't know this terminal
set logscale x
set title "Cable Response via Physical Descripton vs Mathematical Fit"
set xlabel "Frequency"; set ylabel "Amplitude (v)"
set xrange [1e6:1e9]

# plot table into file
set table 'droop.csv'
    plot [f=fmin:fmax] '+' u 1:(exp(-a1*sqrt(f)-a2*f)) w table
unset table

fscale=1e9

# Define pole zero and pole equations
# pole/zero
pz(x,p,z)=(1+((2*pi*x)/(2*pi*z))**2)/(1+((2*pi*x)/(2*pi*p))**2)

# pole
p(x,p)=1/(1+((2*pi*x)/(2*pi*p))**2) # Eq2

# 6-pole fit - cascading 6 pole/zero and one pole utilizing pz(x.p.z) and p(x,p). Where x is the frequency.
f6(x)=sqrt(pz(x,wp1,wz1)*pz(x,wp2,wz2)*pz(x,wp3,wz3)*pz(x,wp4,wz4)*pz(x,wp5,wz5)*p(x,wp6))

# Define our initial estimates
wp1=7e-3*fscale; wz1=8e-3*fscale; wp2=6e-2*fscale; wz2=7e-2*fscale; wp3=2.5e-1*fscale; wz3=3.5e-1*fscale; 
wp4=.25*fscale; wz4=0.1*fscale; wp5=.5*fscale; wz5=1*fscale; wp6=12*fscale

# Call GNUPLOT's "fit" function to calculate poles and zeroes by least square method
# fit f6(x) 'droop.csv' using (10**$1):2 via wp1, wz1, wp2, wz2, wp3, wz3, wp4, wz4, wp5, wz5, wp6
set fit brief
fit f6(x) 'droop.csv' using 1:2 via wp1, wz1, wp2, wz2, wp3, wz3, wp4, wz4, wp5, wz5, wp6

#Overlay the Cable Characteristics vs the Mathematical Fit.
plot 'droop.csv' using 1:2, f6(x)

#Calculate Rs and Cs for pole/zero schematic normalized for a 50 ohm characteristic impedance.
#Pole Zero1
r1= 50*((wz1/wp1)-1);c1=1/(2*pi*50*wz1)
#Pole Zero2
r2= 50*((wz2/wp2)-1);c2=1/(2*pi*50*wz2)
#Pole Zero3
r3= 50*((wz3/wp3)-1);c3=1/(2*pi*50*wz3)
#Pole Zero4
r4= 50*((wz4/wp4)-1);c4=1/(2*pi*50*wz4)
#Pole Zero1
r5= 50*((wz5/wp5)-1);c5=1/(2*pi*50*wz5)
#Last Pole
c6=1/(2*pi*50*wp6)
print "r1=",r1;print "c1=",c1
print "r2=",r2;print "c2=",c2
print "r3=",r3;print "c3=",c3
print "r4=",r4;print "c4=",c4
print "r5=",r5;print "c5=",c5
print "c6=",c6
pause -1 'Hit return to continue'
```

**Result:**

```
After 1530 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 3.2945e-08
rel. change during last iteration : -9.99253e-06

degrees of freedom    (FIT_NDF)                        : 89
rms of residuals      (FIT_STDFIT) = sqrt(WSSR/ndf)    : 1.92398e-05
variance of residuals (reduced chisquare) = WSSR/ndf   : 3.70169e-10

Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
wp1             = 2.046e+06        +/- 5.661e+05    (27.67%)
wz1             = 2.0472e+06       +/- 5.67e+05     (27.7%)
wp2             = 1.51042e+07      +/- 5.652e+05    (3.742%)
wz2             = 1.5144e+07       +/- 5.683e+05    (3.753%)
wp3             = 6.47611e+07      +/- 1.691e+06    (2.61%)
wz3             = 6.5354e+07       +/- 1.72e+06     (2.632%)
wp4             = 2.19839e+08      +/- 4.545e+06    (2.067%)
wz4             = 2.25992e+08      +/- 4.783e+06    (2.116%)
wp5             = 6.88133e+08      +/- 1.077e+07    (1.565%)
wz5             = 7.57217e+08      +/- 1.274e+07    (1.682%)
wp6             = 2.67655e+09      +/- 1.643e+07    (0.6137%)

correlation matrix of the fit parameters:
                wp1    wz1    wp2    wz2    wp3    wz3    wp4    wz4    wp5    wz5    wp6    
wp1             1.000 
wz1             1.000  1.000 
wp2             0.669  0.669  1.000 
wz2             0.669  0.669  1.000  1.000 
wp3             0.359  0.359  0.784  0.785  1.000 
wz3             0.358  0.358  0.782  0.783  1.000  1.000 
wp4             0.202  0.202  0.496  0.496  0.843  0.845  1.000 
wz4             0.199  0.199  0.490  0.491  0.837  0.839  1.000  1.000 
wp5             0.125  0.125  0.317  0.318  0.605  0.607  0.892  0.897  1.000 
wz5             0.121  0.121  0.308  0.308  0.590  0.592  0.879  0.884  0.999  1.000 
wp6             0.096  0.096  0.248  0.248  0.487  0.489  0.774  0.781  0.968  0.975  1.000 
r1=0.0292341284207409
c1=1.55485767177524e-09
r2=0.131551375433137
c2=2.10189190065031e-10
r3=0.457753643018555
c3=4.8705508766561e-11
r4=1.3994726645902
c4=1.40849979941516e-11
r5=5.0196143565562
c5=4.20368268865671e-12
c6=1.18925408734607e-12
```

[image]